# Python script multiexecution

Tags: python, exe

I want to execute three python script that I have developed. I found one doubt, how could I do it using a python script?

I want to convert it into a .exe, because our solution is thought to be executed in machines without python installed so having an unique script would be helpful.

**Edit**: I don't know the cause of the closure, I know how to use pyinstaller, my question was how can I execute 3 python using a python script or if it is possible.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Look at pyinstaller. It's a command line tool to convert python scripts to executables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To package script and all dependencies you can use Pyinstaller, see [here](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/).
To execute multiple script (or exe) you can write a bat file that start the 3 exe or use them as services, based on your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Use [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) it can convert python to executables. You can get it up and running simply by doing

```
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller myfile.py
```